# 200 magic number

Tags: engine, cooling

2005 Pontiac Bonneville 3.8 SE. Temperature steady at 200 degrees constantly. Never goes higher even in stalled traffic. I have actually let the car idle for 1/2 hour and electric fan has NEVER came on and temperature just stays at 200. Fans come on when I put the a/c on, but even then temperature will stay the same. Car runs great and no leaks, codes or other wise. Is this normal or should the fan come on? 195 thermostat. Temperature drops gradually as it cools down after I park it.

Comment: Sounds like your thermostat is working well to me.  How and where are you testing for the temp?  Are you in a cold/cool climate?

Comment: Are you sure your temperature indicator sensor is working correctly, and that it can measure above 200 degrees? Seems like it would go above 200 when idling for a while, unless the fan was running.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tedwin ... it sounds like it's running right where it needs to be. Most GM vehicles I've run (and that's quite a few of them) have had the temp gauge read right about the middle of the gauge. While the dash gauge isn't uber accurate, 200°F is right about where a 195°F stat should be running at. As long as it isn't going above it and you have no other signs it's doing anything but running right, I believe you're good to go.